# Who CAN'T attain moksha?

Tags: moksha

I've seen [a](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/can-commoners-attain-moksha-without-needing-to-be-born-as-a-brahmin) [bunch](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55347/can-shudras-attain-moksha) [of](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55244/to-attain-moksha-must-you-be-born-as-a-hindu) [questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/can-animals-attain-moksha) that ask about moksha and the limits on who can attain it.

What I'm wondering is, is there any group of people or type of person for whom the attainment of moksha is explicitly forbidden or said to be impossible?

As far as I can tell, anyone who is a proper devotee may attain it:

> In whatever way people surrender unto Me, I reciprocate accordingly. Everyone follows My path, knowingly or unknowingly, O son of Pritha. [Bhagavat Gita 4.11]

And the Bhagavatam gives a long list of races, creatures, and types of people who have attained it:

> In different ages many beings with Rajas and Tamas predominating in them - Asuras, Rakshas, beasts, birds, Gandharvas, Apsaras, serpents, Siddhas, Charanas, Guhyakas, Vidyadharas, and among human beings, unqualified persons like women, Vaisyas, Sudras and outcastes - all have attained to My being by the power of holy association alone. [Srimad Bhagavatam 11.12.3-7]

But is there any type of individual who is considered unable to attain moksha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krishna explains in chapter 16 of Bhagavad Gita:

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/16/verse/4

> दम्भो दर्पोऽभिमानश्च क्रोध: पारुष्यमेव च |
> अज्ञानं चाभिजातस्य पार्थ सम्पदमासुरीम् || 4||

> दैवी सम्पद्विमोक्षाय निबन्धायासुरी मता |
> मा शुच: सम्पदं दैवीमभिजातोऽसि पाण्डव || 5||

> द्वौ भूतसर्गौ लोकेऽस्मिन्दैव आसुर एव च |
> दैवो विस्तरश: प्रोक्त आसुरं पार्थ मे शृणु || 6||

> प्रवृत्तिं च निवृत्तिं च जना न विदुरासुरा: |
> न शौचं नापि चाचारो न सत्यं तेषु विद्यते || 7||

> असत्यमप्रतिष्ठं ते जगदाहुरनीश्वरम् |
> अपरस्परसम्भूतं किमन्यत्कामहैतुकम् || 8||

> एतां दृष्टिमवष्टभ्य नष्टात्मानोऽल्पबुद्धय: |
> प्रभवन्त्युग्रकर्माण: क्षयाय जगतोऽहिता: || 9||

> काममाश्रित्य दुष्पूरं दम्भमानमदान्विता: |
> मोहाद्गृहीत्वासद्ग्राहान्प्रवर्तन्तेऽशुचिव्रता: || 10||

> चिन्तामपरिमेयां च प्रलयान्तामुपाश्रिता: |
> कामोपभोगपरमा एतावदिति निश्चिता: || 11||

> आशापाशशतैर्बद्धा: कामक्रोधपरायणा: |
> ईहन्ते कामभोगार्थमन्यायेनार्थसञ्जयान् || 12||

.....................

> अनेकचित्तविभ्रान्ता मोहजालसमावृता: |
> प्रसक्ता: कामभोगेषु पतन्ति नरकेऽशुचौ || 16||

...................

> तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |
> क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु || 19||
> आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा जन्मनि जन्मनि |
> मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || 20||

> त्रिविधं नरकस्येदं द्वारं नाशनमात्मन: |
> काम: क्रोधस्तथा लोभस्तस्मादेतत्त्रयं त्यजेत् || 21||

> BG 16.4: O Parth, the qualities of those who possess a demoniac nature are hypocrisy, arrogance, conceit, anger, harshness, and ignorance.

> BG 16.5: The divine qualities lead to liberation, while the demoniac qualities are the cause for a continuing destiny of bondage. Grieve not, O Arjun, as you were born with saintly virtues.

> BG 16.6: There are two kinds of beings in this world—those endowed with a divine nature and those possessing a demoniac nature. I have described the divine qualities in detail, O Arjun. Now hear from me about the demoniac nature.

> BG 16.7: Those possessing a demoniac nature do not comprehend which actions are proper and which are improper. Hence, they possess neither purity, nor good conduct, nor even truthfulness.

> BG 16.8: They say, “The world is without Absolute Truth, without any basis (for moral order), and without a God (who has created or is controlling it). It is created from the combination of the two sexes, and has no purpose other than sexual gratification.”

> BG 16.9: Holding fast to such views, these misdirected souls, with small intellect and cruel actions, arise as enemies of the world threatening its destruction.

> BG 16.10: Harboring insatiable lust, full of hypocrisy, pride and arrogance, the demoniac cling to their false tenets. Thus illusioned, they are attracted to the impermanent and work with impure

> BG 16.11: They are obsessed with endless anxieties that end only with death. Still, they maintain with complete assurance that gratification of desires and accumulation of wealth is the highest purpose of life.

> BG 16.12: Held in bondage by hundreds of desires, and driven by lust and anger, they strive to accumulate wealth by unjust means, all for the gratification of their senses.

....................

> BG 16.16: Possessed and led astray by such imaginings, enveloped in a mesh of delusion, and addicted to the gratification of sensuous pleasures, they descend to the murkiest hell.

.............

> **BG 16.19-20: These cruel and hateful persons, the vile and vicious of humankind, I constantly hurl into the wombs of those with similar demoniac natures in the cycle of rebirth in the material world. These ignorant souls take birth again and again in demoniac wombs. Failing to reach Me, O Arjun, they gradually sink to the most abominable type of existence.**

> BG 16.21: There are three gates leading to the hell of self-destruction for the soul—lust, anger, and greed. Therefore, one should abandon all three.